# Magento 2 : From where the total discount from cart is returned

Tags: magento2, quote, quoteitem

I need to know from where the total discount after all validation & calculation is returned for a cart ?

I need to get total discount for a cart/quote.

Comment: have you check the quote tables?

Comment: Thanks Dhiren for the comment, yes i have i did not found field for discount
Though i found "subtotal_with_discount" & "base_subtotal_with_discount"

Comment: from that diffrent field, you can able to get the value which you want there.

Comment: Actually i am looking for a direct method (if available)
in module-sales-rule from where the discount amount is returned for cart
on applying coupon

Comment: any thoughts on this ?

Comment: specify your requirement in details then we can give you suggestion accordingly, otherwise amount you can take it from this calculation.